# How Do I prompt the user to re-enter his/her input if it doesn't meet my condition?

Tags: java

I am trying to get the user to enter the number of adults, and for the program to continue running, the condition is (adults>0). How do I rewrite my code so that if the user enters any value that is <=0, it displays the message "Wrong input, Try again!" and allows the user to re-enter the input.

Here's my code so far:

```
if (achoice.equals("1")) {
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.print("\tEnter number of adults: ");
int adults = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Put it inside a while loop.

Comment: How? I tried to but whenever i do it just repeats the statement afterwards infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
do {
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("\tEnter number of adults: ");
    int adults = input.nextInt();
} while (adults <= 0);
```